# How to remove date and month from the column (type:datetime64)

Tags: python-3.x

I have 10 columns (dtype: datetime64). I want to remove the date and month from the columns and keep only the year.

10-01-1880 --> Would like to remove day and month

expecting --> 1880

Comment: `df['column'].dt.year`

Comment: @coldspeed ... showing error  df['year'].dt.year  AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: From the observation, I can conclude that the type is indeed not `datetime64`. Please verify this information before posting next time... For now, you can do `pd.to_datetime(df['column'], errors='coerce').dt.year`.

Comment: @coldspeed... I have already converted my column using pd.to_datetime  Name: year, dtype: datetime64[ns].. now I used your code... it showing                                                l0     1970
1     1970
2     1970
3     1970
4     1970
5     1970
6     1970
7     1970
8     1970
9     1970
10    1970
11    1970
12    1970
13    1970
14    1970
15    1970
16    1970
Name: year, dtype: int64

Comment: @coldspeed.. I have column which has date-month-year for 25 rows.. I want to remove the date and month and keep the year..

Comment: You can't remove the date and month and still retain the type... the year is an integer, so you get a column of integers as a result.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. I am using datetime module https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

```
from datetime import datetime

#Convert string to datetime object
datetime_object = datetime.strptime('10-01-1880', '%d-%m-%Y')
#Extract year
print(datetime_object.day)
print(datetime_object.month)
print(datetime_object.year)
#10
#1
#1880
```

Comment: Thanks. How it works If I want to do the entire column?

Comment: You mean date, month and year?

Comment: yes. I want to do for entire column

Comment: Done please check